# Outlook 2010 not scaling images on 125% machines

Tags: html, css, image, email, outlook

First, I'm fully aware of the issues behind Outlook and how it uses Word to render its HTML/CSS, as well as the DPI issues at hand.

It's important to note I am sending my emails *from* Outlook 2010, and not from some other client.  Because of my situation, it's my only option.

Here's my problem:  I've tried many variations of code, and I cannot get Outlook to correctly scale embedded images.  People who receive my email and are at 125% dpi, *everything* scales up 25% *except* the images; those all remain at their exact original pixel size.  Even changing the DPI of the images has absolutely no effect, they are rendered exactly the same.  I almost would have expected the images to scale up...

I have tried the solutions outlined [here](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/151-mystery-solved-dpi-scaling-in-outlook-2007-2013) but it seems to have no effect.  They advise using this code:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
  <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
```

However with or without that code, it seems to have no effect.  My images never scale up on someone with a 125% dpi Windows machine.

I have tried explicitly defining widths of my table cells, with and without using inline styles, and it has absolutely no effect.  I'm beginning to wonder if maybe the problem is that I'm sending the email from Outlook 2010 itself.

It works perfectly if the recipient is at 100% (which is what I'm running at) but otherwise, the images just refuse to scale.  I've noticed if I manually insert images through Outlook, it takes into account the DPI of the image, but I can't get my code to obey it.

Is there something else specific I need to do to get the images to scale up with the rest of the tables, etc.?  I'm usually able to figure these things out, but this is just driving me nuts.

Comment: So this is really strange... I've been tinkering with this some more, and found what seems to be the culprit, only I am not sure why.

When I removed align="center" from my img tag or change it to left aligned... POOF, the image is now resizing correctly!  The same applies to the <td> tag that the image is inside of.  If the <td> tag has align="center" it WILL NOT resize the image correctly on 125% computers.  But if I change it to left align or remove it completely, the image resizes appropriately.  What the heck??